# Can we parameterize the url of HTTP POST Request while creating Logic apps in devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

Hi I am new to LogicApps and want to understand if it is possible that while creating/designing a logic app to send email, can we parameterize the HTTP Post Method URL, that is auto-generated?

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by paramterize the url?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a possibility to accept parameters in the endpoint URL, then: yes, you can.

Taken from [Accept parameters in endpoint URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint#accept-parameters-in-endpoint-url):

> When you want your endpoint URL to accept parameters, specify the **relative path** in your trigger. You also need to explicitly set the method that your HTTP request expects.